# how to test jwt authentication using Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, postman

I have an API which i implemented jwt for the authentication,here is my authentication:

```
         [Route("api/[controller]")]
            [ApiController]
            public class AuthController : ControllerBase
            {

                [HttpPost, Route("login")]
                public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginModel user)
                {
                   if (user == null)
                    {
                        return BadRequest("Invalid client request");
                    }


                    if (user.UserName == "test" && user.Password == "1234")
                    {

                        var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("sretKey@345"));
                        var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                        var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(

                            issuer: "https://localhost:44361",
                            audience: "https://localhost:44378",
                            claims: new List<Claim>(),
                            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(25),
                            signingCredentials: signinCredentials
                        );
```

and in postman here is the error [image: Error]

in my controller, I added the authorize attribute, I tested my controller without authorizing attribute and it works, the problem is why it unauthorized me with credentials

here is my startup

```
             public class Startup
            {
                public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
                {
                    Configuration = configuration;
                }

                public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

                // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
                public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
                {
                    services.AddAuthentication(opt => {
                        opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    })
                    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                    {
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                            ValidateLifetime = true,
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                            ValidIssuer = "https://localhost:44361",
                            ValidAudience = "https://localhost:44378",
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("sretKey@345"))
                        };
                    });

                    services.AddCors(options =>
                    {
                        options.AddPolicy("EnableCORS", builder =>
                        {
                            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:44378")
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod();
                        });
                    });




                    services.AddDbContext<DbContextClass>(options =>
                    options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


               
                    services.AddControllers();

                }

                // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
                public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
                {
                    if (env.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                    }

                    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

                    app.UseRouting();

                    app.UseAuthorization();

                    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                    {
                        endpoints.MapControllers();
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add AllowAnonymous to your login action

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
 [HttpPost("login")]
 public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginModel user)
{
.... your code
var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions);
return Ok(token);
}
```

After this you have to configure the startup  to use this token. And also you have to add this token to Postman for action testing. Postman has a special menu Autorization. Open it , select token option and paste your token in the field. Instead of login and pass put your input action parameters if needed

And try to add app.UseAuthentication() like this:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: im still geting  unauthorize

Comment: you have to configure the startup to use this token. And did you put this token to the postman?

Comment: should I share my sturtup?

Comment: Yes, and did you assign this token to Postman for testing?

Comment: i have edited the question by adding the sturtup,what dou mean by adding the token to postman,i thought once i give the correct username and pass ,postman should return me a token,is not it?

Comment: No ,  it is not working. Postman has a special option Autorization, open it , select token and paste your token. Instead of login and pass put your input action parameters if needed.

Comment: to be honest with you i dont know which token should be added

Comment: At first call login action using your password and user name. It should return token, if you fixed your code according to my answer. After this you can copy token (without "") and use it to test another actions.

Comment: I followed what you said, first i sent a request to Auth/Login,it returned me a token, then i used the token in Postman to send a request to another Action, but i get unauthorize!

Comment: @mortezasol Check my answer. Try to add app.UseAuthentication();

Comment: thanks a lot it works!just one more question,im supposed to give this API to a company that need to consume it in their app, how they should use it? should i ask them to send a request to our login API ?!because without the token they cant access the controller they need,sorry for asking too many questions

Comment: Yes, they have to obtain a token at  fisrt before using APIs. They can use your compay login, you can make a special login API for them. Login api should have Anounymous attribute.

Comment: thanks a lot,you saved me!it used to be basicAuth before i changed it to JWT,do you think its better and more secure now?

Comment: jwt isn't more secure than basicAuth, jwt is useful because you can use the token across services without having to reauthenticate